# How can I log all the incoming requests and the outbound responses to all api's in sanic

Tags: python, sanic

I've tried logging in every function, but in order to make a generic one and avoid having the same logger.info(), I want to use the logging property of sanic.

Researching for it I got the info of rotating logger, but it doesnt log the request data and its headers as well as the responses being sent.
What should I include in the logging config for that?

This is my log config

```
LOG_SETTINGS = {
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': False,
        'handlers': {
            'rotating_log_handler': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
                'filename': '/var/log/fynd/hogwarts.log',
                'maxBytes': 1024 * 1024 * 50,
                'backupCount': 10,
                'formatter': 'log_formatter'
            },
            'console': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                'formatter': 'console'
            },
        },
        'formatters': {
            'log_formatter': {
                '()': 'pycommon.logger.jsonformatter.JsonFormatter',
            },
            'console': {
                'format': '[%(asctime)s][%(levelname)s] %(name)s '
                          '%(filename)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d | %(message)s',
                'datefmt': '%H:%M:%S',
            },
        },
        'loggers': {
            '': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'handlers': ['rotating_log_handler'],
                'propagate': True
            },
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem with logging for me.

```
from sanic import Sanic, json
from sanic.request import Request as SanicRequest
from sanic.response import BaseHTTPResponse as SanicResponse, HTTPResponse
from sanic.views import HTTPMethodView
from sanic.log import logger

app = Sanic("test_app")


class View1(HTTPMethodView):
    async def get(self, request: SanicRequest) -> HTTPResponse:
        logger.info("view1")
        return json(body="view1 executed")


class View2(HTTPMethodView):
    async def get(self, request: SanicRequest) -> HTTPResponse:
        logger.info("view2")
        return json(body="view2 executed")


@app.middleware("request")
async def callback_request(request: SanicRequest) -> None:
    logger.info(f"Request {request.path} received.")


@app.middleware("response")
async def callback_response(request: SanicRequest, response: SanicResponse) -> None:
    logger.info(f"Request {request.path} processing finished.")


app.add_route(View1.as_view(), "/view1")
app.add_route(View2.as_view(), "/view2")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8888)
```